# decimal custom format string with fixed precision and no period

Tags: c#, decimal, format-string

I've run into a situation which I think is beyond what you can do with custom format strings.

But the code I've written is so gross I thought I would ask anyway.

What I need is for a decimal to be displayed as either a 6 or 7 digit string, like so:

```
number = 12345.67M
(optional)
tenthousands thousands hundreds tens ones tenths hundredths
     1          2         3      4    5     6        7
```

Here's the code I've written to achieve this:

```
public static string ConvertDecimalToString(decimal easting, int length)
{
    var formatString = "{0:0000.00}";
    var numberAsString = string.Format(formatString, easting);
    var removePeriod = numberAsString.Replace(".", "");

    if (removePeriod.Length > length)
    {
        return removePeriod.Substring(removePeriod.Length - length, length);
    }
    else
    {
        return removePeriod.PadLeft(length, '0');
    }
}
```

---

Expected inputs and outputs:

```
Input           Output(6)    Output(7)
912345.67M      234567       1234567
12345.67M       234567       1234567
1234.56M        123456       0123456
1234.5M         123450       0123450
1234M           123400       0123400
234M            023400       0023400
```

Comment: So what does your expected output look like for input = 12345.67M and input = 1234.56M?

Comment: Why do you think custom format strings won't work?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind "234567" (Output(6), first example). i.e. removing (very) significant digits?

Comment: Yeah, removing the most and the least significant digits because they are unlikely to introduce clashes in the string produced.

Comment: So what is the bigger picture here? What to you try to achieve? What are this limited-length strings for?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a decimal `12345.67`displayed as `1234567` (just omit the decimal point) use this trick:

```
decimal number = 12345.67M;
string s = string.Format("{0:0000000}", number * 100.0);
```

**Or**

```
string s = string.Format("{0:F0}", number * 100.0); // zero decimal places
```

Morale: Do not fiddle with a string produced from formatting, modify the input value instead and let the formatting do its job.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294501/print-constant-exponent-value-using-printf-in-c/29294667#29294667

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle the max string length, but it does avoid a string replace at the cost of a multiplication. Anyway, (and I'm really not trying to be belligerent here in case the tone comes across as snappy) it doesn't prove the point of letting the format string do the work.

Comment: @Coxy In the general case you have varying decimal separators (`,` in Germany) which the formatting handels correctly, but not your string replacement. This is just one example for the underlying reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to separate your number to digits

str=number.ToSting()
 will give a string you can iterate and create your number

str.split('.')
will give you both sides of the number
Then you will be able to build your stribg number dynamicly without forcing a format